# reverseGeocodeLocation: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CLPlacemark' with an argument list of type '(placemark: CLPlacemark)'"

Tags: swift2, cllocation, xcode7-beta4

I am stumped on how to initializer this placemark within my reverseGeocodeLocation attempt.

First, I do not know if the reverseGeocodeLocation is initialized correctly. It was giving me some issues; but Xcode seems to be okay with it at this point.

The real issue comes at line 55: 
placemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarkArr[0] as! CLPlacemark)

I receive the error: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CLPlacemark' with an argument list of type '(place mark: CLPlacemark)'"

I am using Xcode 7 Beta 4; so I don't know if this could be the issue. I have seen older examples on how to write this line of code, but they all appear to be earlier code editions.

Thanks for any help or suggestions! This one has been stumping me for a while.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    var manager:CLLocationManager?

    @IBOutlet weak var latitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var longitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var altitude: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var course: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var speed: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var address: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manager = CLLocationManager()
        manager!.delegate = self
        manager!.desiredAccuracy - kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager!.startUpdatingLocation()

    }


    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print(locations)
        let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]
        self.latitude.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
        self.longitude.text = "\(userLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
        self.course.text = "\(userLocation.course)"
        self.speed.text = "\(userLocation.speed)"
        self.altitude.text = "\(userLocation.altitude)"

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarkArr, error) -> Void in

            var placemark:CLPlacemark!
            //let gp = userLocation

            if error == nil && placemarkArr!.count > 0 {
                print(userLocation)

                placemark = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarkArr[0] as! CLPlacemark)

                var addressString: String = ""
                if placemark.ISOcountryCode == "TW" {
                    if placemark.country != nil {
                    addressString = placemark.country!
                    }
                    if placemark.subAdministrativeArea != nil {
                    addressString = addressString + placemark.subAdministrativeArea! + ", "
                    }
                    if placemark.postalCode != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placemark.postalCode! + " "
                    }
                    if placemark.locality != nil {
                        addressString = addressString + placemark.locality!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




}
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no longer having this issue. My code may be slightly different than above, so I have pasted below the portion of my code initializing the reverseGeocodeLocation:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate{

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

var longitude: Double!
var latitude: Double!

var thoroughfare = "unknown"
var subLocality = "unknown"
var subAdministrativeArea = "unknown"
var postCode = "unknown"
var locality = "unknown"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0]

    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(userLocation) { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

        if(error == nil) {
            let loc = placemarks![0]

            self.thoroughfare = String!(loc.thoroughfare)
            self.subLocality = String!(loc.subLocality)
            self.subAdministrativeArea = String!(loc.subAdministrativeArea)
            self.postCode = String!(loc.postalCode)
            self.locality = String!(loc.locality)
    } else {
            //print(error)
        }
        print("thoroughfare: " + self.thoroughfare)
    }
}
```

Comment: So what, exactly, was the problem?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure. If you read my first post, Xcode did not like that code. The code in my answer is slightly different, but the issue could have been resolved by a number of things:
1. Updates in Xcode and Swift
2. Updates in the Parse libraries
3. Or the slight changes in my coding examples.